# Stuck on filling options of HTML select in a modal popup in codeiginiter php

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu, modalpopup

I am trying to put dynamic key and value to the dropdown. which is an HTML select type. The component is part of modal popup. I am getting trouble in passing the array list to the modal popup

```
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/addItemToInventory" >
            <input type="hidden" name="txtpatient" id="txtpatient">


            </div>
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-md-6" >
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label>Choose Inventroy Level of Item </label>
                         <select name="selectInventory" id="selectInventory" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-info btn-block" title="Single Select" data-size="7">
                                                <option value="1">Full</option>
                                                <option value="2">Half-Full</option>
                                                <option value="3">Half-Empty</option>
                                                <option value="4">Empty</option>
                                                <option value="5">Emergency</option>
                                            </select>
```

The array list with necessary data are already avilable as data-id=""

```
 <a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddInventory" data-patient="$inventory[0]["PatientId"]" data-id="<?php $doctor ?>" style="float:right" class="btn btn-success chk1item" >Add Item</a>
```

I am looking to replace the hardcoded options with dynamic​ values from database

Comment: data-patient and data-id: please check what is the output in your browser console! in your example, you don't echo this out!

Comment: empty are those in javascript. but in controller thoese are not empty